# verification call was successful or not by twilio verification call

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio Appi for phone verification my this snippet is generating verification call.

```
ValidationRequestResult result = client.AddOutgoingCallerId(options.To, GeneratedVerificationOption());
```

i want to  check that either call was successful or not

Answer (score 0):

The `AddOutgoingCallerId` method accepts a `OutgoingCallerIdOptions` object as a method parameter, which you can use to provide a [`StatusCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#status-callback-parameter) URL.

```
var options = OutgoingCallerIdOptions() { StatusCallback="http://example.com/result" }
result = client.AddOutgoingCallerId("+15555555555", options);
if (result.RestException!=null) {
    Debug.Writeline("error making validation phone call");
}
```

Twilio will make a request to this URL when the verification call completes, passing you the result of the verification as the `VerificationStatus` parameter.  If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can just add this as an action method parameter:

```
public ActionMethod PostResult(string VerificationStatus) {
    if (VerificationStatus=="success") {

    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Dvein rader for your respone

Comment: It will, but you will need to use a tool like ngrok (ngrok.com) to expore your local website out to the public internet via a public domain.  In that case the StatusCallback value would be `[yourdomain].ngrok.io/[YourRoute]/`

Comment: Hey @Devin i am not able to get status of call,
I am generating call like this

`'ValidationRequestResult result = client.AddOutgoingCallerId("+16099575303", GeneratedVerificationOption());`
Below is the method to generate options
`public OutgoingCallerIdOptions GeneratedVerificationOption()
        {
            OutgoingCallerIdOptions options = new OutgoingCallerIdOptions();
            options.StatusCallback = "http://7a37fb95.ngrok.io/Home/PostResult";
      //      options.StatusCallbackMethod = "POST";

            return options;

        }`

and my target action is like

Comment: Do you see the HTTP request fom Twilio logged by ngrok?  Have you checked the Twilio logs to see if your application is returning an error to Twilio?